# Xamarin iOS free provisioning fails for existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, ios-provisioning

I have recently been given the task of taking over an existing iOS/Android app written with **Xamarin**.

When I try to set up **Free Provisioning as described in [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)** in the Xamarin guides, I run into a roadblock:

I have successfully followed these steps:

1. Created an Apple ID
2. Went to XCode -> Preferences and added my account
3. Created the signing identity as described at step 4 of the guide
4. Plugged in my dev iPhone (freshly updated)
5. Under "General Options" I set the Bundle Identifier to the exact string that is set in the iOS project part of the Xamarin solution
6. Selected myself from the team dropdown
7. **Pressed "Fix Issues" as per guide, and this is where the procedure fails**

**The error I get is "An App ID with identifier 'xx.xx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxx' is not available. Please enter a different string.**

If I try and add a anything to the identifier, it works (so it's not the format of the identifier).
The error message also **makes sense** to me as the identifier is, indeed, globally taken since the **app has already been published**.

My question here is:
**How can I get my project deployed to my dev iPhone?**

Comment: A possible workaround could be to change the BundleIdentifier for the time you are working on a specific task. This should work but it brings the disadvantages of changing the identifier every time and if you do not watch out to check in the false identifier by accident.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input! I would like to solve this the "proper" way, but I will keep your suggestion as a last resort.

Comment: @tequilaslammer If you post your comment as answer I'd like to mark yours as the correct answer, since you were first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have already posted as a comment:

A possible workaround could be to change the BundleIdentifier for the time you are working on a specific task. This should work but it brings the disadvantages of changing the identifier every time and if you do not watch out to check in the false identifier by accident.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose : **"com.companyname.yourapp1"** or  **"com.companyname.yourapp2"**.

Make sure this ID is same like your bundle identifier in **"Info.plist"** in xamarin.ios project

Comment: Thank you for your input as well. I wanted to avoid this step to keep the environment as close to publish as I can, but it looks like this is what I'll have to do.